# public tunnel into private behind-nat machine

Tags: networking, web-server, nat

Say I have a web server running on my local machine which is connected to the internet but behind NAT (let's just assume it cannot be reached directly from the outside but It can open TCP/UDP communications outside)

I'd lik to have a public IP that tunnels into my machine (in specific ports) and that I can turn on and off at will so that in theory anyone in the world would be able  to access the local web server I'm running.

Is there a paid service like that?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished very simply by renting a small VPS somewhere and then using SSH tunneling to expose a local port on your laptop via a public IP of the VPS.